# Work command handler for an economy system

Tags: python, python-3.x, cyclomatic-complexity, pymongo

I have been working on this code, which is the part of an economy system that handles the work command. This lets the user pick a role and if they have enough level then they will get it by updating a db.

I know it's inefficient and I am unsure how to reduce the if count and keeping a cyclomatic complexity below 15. I need to add 8 more jobs but I can't add anymore.

- How can I reduce the if count?
- What else have I done wrong?

### The code I have been working on

```py
  @job.command()
  async def apply(self,ctx,*,selection:str):
    a = banned(ctx.author.id,self.bot.blacklisted)
    if a is True:
      return await ctx.send("You are blacklisted from using this command.")
    db = client.bot
    posts = db.user
    for x in posts.find({"guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}","id":f"{ctx.author.id}"},{ "_id": 0,"job":1,"level":1}):
      level = int(x["level"])
    if selection.lower() == "garbage collector" and level >= 0:
      posts.update_one({"id":f"{ctx.author.id}","guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}"}, {"$set": { "job": "Garbage Collector","income":50}})#save
    elif selection.lower() == "cleaner" and level >= 7:
      posts.update_one({"id":f"{ctx.author.id}","guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}"}, {"$set": { "job": "Cleaner","income":70}})#save
    elif selection.lower() == "car washer" and level >= 16:
      posts.update_one({"id":f"{ctx.author.id}","guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}"}, {"$set": { "job": "Car Washer","income":105}})#save
    elif selection.lower() == "maid" and level >= 27:
      posts.update_one({"id":f"{ctx.author.id}","guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}"}, {"$set": { "job": "Maid","income":145}})#save
    elif selection.lower() == "receptionist" and level >= 36:
      posts.update_one({"id":f"{ctx.author.id}","guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}"}, {"$set": { "job": "Receptionist","income":185}})#save
    else:
      return await ctx.send(f"You are currently {level}, please go to school using ?learn")
    await ctx.send(f"You are now working as a {selection.lower()}")
```

### The pymongo document format

```py
"id":f"{message.author.id}"
"name":f"{message.author.name}"
"guildid":f"{message.guild.id}"
"cash":0
"job":"Homeless"
"balance":0
"shares":0
"level":0
"income":0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why loop?

```
for x in posts.find({"guildid":f"{ctx.guild.id}","id":f"{ctx.author.id}"},{ "_id": 0,"job":1,"level":1}):
  level = int(x["level"])
```

You're looping over the result of `posts.find` to... convert an element to an integer and then throw it away? Are you sure that this is what you want to be doing?

If you care about `level`, your current code is overwriting it on every iteration, so you'll only get the last one.

### Don't repeat yourself

```
for job_name, level_min, income in (
   ('Garbage Collector',  0,  50),
   (          'Cleaner',  7,  70),
   (       'Car Washer', 16, 105),
   (             'Maid', 27, 145),
   (     'Receptionist', 36, 185)
):
    if selection.lower() == job_name.lower() and level >= level_min:
        data = {
           "id": f"{ctx.author.id}",
           "guildid": f"{ctx.guild.id}"
        }
        set_stuff = {
          "$set": {
              "job": job_name,
              "income": income
          }
        }
        posts.update_one(data, set_stuff)
        break
else:
    return await ctx.send(f"You are currently {level}, please go to school using ?learn")
```

If you want to get fancier, you can use a case-insensitive dictionary, but for this, that isn't strictly needed.

Comment: Thank you, is there a guide or something to learn how to make code like that?

Comment: Making what kind of code, in particular? Yes, there are some online Python guides.

Comment: Really efficient code like yours

Comment: It basically takes practice and experience. Read books and other peoples' source code, and keep submitting to CodeReview :)